# Use backup function vim to make a copy on write

Tags: vim, backup

I am using `set backup` in my `.vimrc` to automatically backup files on every write. This backs up the *original* (old) file however, not the newly written file. Is there an elegant, preferably built-in way to backup the new file instead?

The reason I am interested in this, by the way, is that I am using [gitwatch](https://github.com/nevik/gitwatch) to automatically commit my backup directory when it changes. This way, I always have a perfect history available of all my files.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am currently using:

```
augroup rewrite
   autocmd!
   autocmd BufWrite * :w
augroup END
```

On every write, I write again.

This seems to work altough I am wondering why it doesn't get stuck in a loop.